# Zen Coding Plugin Install for Sublime Text 2 portable in Window

Tags: sublimetext

I have already downloaded portable software for sublime Text editor. But, I don't know how to install zen coding in that portable. When I google about that issues, I found some installation guide line but not on portable sublime text editor. Please, anyone can help me? Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

To install “Package Control,” open Sublime and press Control + `.

```
import urllib2,os;pf='Package Control.sublime-package';ipp=sublime.installed_packages_path();os.makedirs(ipp) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None;open(os.path.join(ipp,pf),'wb').write(urllib2.urlopen('http://sublime.wbond.net/'+pf.replace(' ','%20')).read())
```

Lastly, restart Sublime Text, and browse to Preferences -> Package Settings. If the installation was successful, you’ll now see a Package Control item in that list.